# What is special about this grid?

Tags: mathematics, letter-sequence

Here is a simple grid with letters in them?

[image: ![enter image description here]

There is **one** significant word and **ten** special numbers in it.

Four questions:

1. What is the significant word?
2. What are the ten special numbers contained in it?
3. Where are they located?
4. What is "fun" name for this grid?

For those who want to copy the grid in text format.

```
E   D   S   Q   U   A   R   E   S
R   N   I   N   E   S   I   X   T
D   Y   E   N   T   Y   F   I   Y
N   T   W   R   N   I   N   V   F
U   R   T   U   O   N   E   E   O
H   O   N   O   F   E   S   T   U
E   F   E   E   T   X   I   H   R
N   X   I   S   Y   T   R   I   E
O   E   N   O   Y   T   H   G   I
```

Hint

> It is a fun puzzle. Nothing serious about it. Targeted for fifth graders.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The [answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izuys.png).

> The first ten square numbers, and the word "Squares".

Completing the solution with a image.

> [image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Great Spotting !!!

Comment: @kanchirk It should probably be noted that $7^2$ is *forty-nine*, not *fo* ***u*** *rty-nine*.  Kind of messes up the whole puzzle, though.  :(

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain Thank you. You are right if it is American English. I spelt it the 'India' english way I was taught. In that case, I would pluralize the ending Squares.

Comment: @kanchirk It appears you were [taught the wrong spelling](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26710/why-is-forty-spelled-without-a-u-in-canadian-british-english).  It is correctly spelled "forty" in all dialects of English.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain You are correct. I just checked myself on the net. Plus 1 for you. I will edit the question and the answer asap.

Comment: @kanchirk -- if you're going to edit the answer, you might edit the first part as well (where is refers to the grid containing "Square" vice "Squares"

Answer (score 6):

Since Pete has already come up with a creative  name, I will toss my suggestion into the hat as well...

> Square Square Spiral

Answer (score 6):

I'll add my suggestion for a a title too. I'm a fan of the much terser

> Spiral²

Additionally, if you like puns you might try

> Squarey-go-Round!

Comment: good idea. Just remember it is a fun name targetted for 5th graders.

Comment: @kanchirk Added a more fun one ;)

Answer (score 3):

@McMagister has solved this, I'm just going to answer part 4), the fun name for this grid. My suggestion:

> Ever decreasing squares

Comment: Not bad.. this can have a better.